# Is it possible to automate correction of tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

A lot of people already wrote about a problematic [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) tag, which was created for a Unity IOC, but is constantly used for Unity game engine by new users, instead of the [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) tag. I spend a lot of time correcting the tags, but I noticed that my (and other users) work could be easily automated — if the user used words like "game", `MonoBehaviour`, `GameObject` and other Unity3d related terms, it was a question with a misplaced [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) tag. I have never saw a question which had any of these words and was really about Unity IOC.

Is there a possibility to automate it, so that SO will switch the tag (or remove [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) if [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) is already present) if the question contains any of these keywords?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic retagging at the time of posting a question is not good idea. It might still introduce false positives: [`[unity] game is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[unity]%20game%20is%3Aq).

It would be better show a modal dialog with the suggestion to retag [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) to [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) if some phrases where detected that signify it is probably about the game engine.

Something like:

> It seems that you're asking about the Unity Game Engine. You might want to retag your questions from [unity] to [unity3d] in order to reach the proper audience.

I don't have the proper domain knowledge about the Unity engine to know how the detection actually might be accomplished.

I also don't know whether the reverse also happens (questions regarding IoC or DI mistagged with [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)).

Comment: There are already wrong suggestions as it is now. At times, when I ask why a question got tagged with both C and C++, the answer is "well SO suggested it". So it's not a clear-cut case.

Comment: @Jongware C & C++ is a much more complicated case than Unity IOC and Unity game engine. A lot of valid C code and C knowledge can be applied to C++ (and vice versa), but Unity3d-specific and Unity IOC-specific questions have very little in common.